# how we create textField in clicking UIBarButton "add"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)] autorelease];
}

-(IBAction) add :(id)sender {

}
```

in view textfield not find the trick is when I click the add textfiled appears in view

Comment: when i click in barbuttonItem textField appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the textfield ahead of time add it to your view and set the hidden property to YES and in add you just make it visible by setting hidden to NO.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    // retaining property
    self.myTextField = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
    myTextField.hidden = YES;

    [newView addSubview:myTextField];

    self.view = newView;
    [newView release];
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender 
{
    myTextField.hidden = NO;
}
```

**Adding a new UITextField every time add is called**

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender 
{
    UITextField * textfieldToAdd = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
    // ... configuration code for textfield ...
    [self.view addSubview:textfieldToAdd];
}
```

Comment: thanks but  if I want to add a new textField every time when I click on add